# Use AWS ElastiCache client for local memcached server

Tags: java, amazon-elasticache

I have been trying, without success, to use ElastiCache client with a memcached server installed on localhost. The webapp, in production, runs in AWS env but during development, I want to use the same ElastiCache client jar with my local memcached server. I currently am falling back to using the spymemcached client jar for development.

I want to avoid recompiling the application with different jars for production and development. Is there a way to configure the ElastiCache client for localhost use?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same thing and rapidly coming to the conclusion that the answer is "no"...

Answer (score 2):

I have just been trying the same thing, and I think I've got it working. Have a look at [Amazon's MemcachedClient](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-elasticache-cluster-client-memcached-for-java/blob/master/src/main/java/net/spy/memcached/MemcachedClient.java)'s constructors. You need to get the clientMode set to ClientMode.Static to connect to a normal memcached server or ClientMode.Dynamic to connect to ElastiCache with auto-discovery. Depending on which constructor you use, you could pass in a ConnectionFactory with clientMode set to static, or you could pass in an address that doesn't contain ".cfg.".

I am using Spring, so I've created a class that extends MemcachedClientFactoryBean to set the clientMode on the connectionFactory.

```
<bean id="memcachedClient" class="au.com.mycompany.MyMemcachedClientFactoryBean">
    <property name="servers" value="${memcached.server}"/>
    <property name="protocol" value="BINARY"/>
    <property name="transcoder">
      <bean class="net.spy.memcached.transcoders.SerializingTranscoder">
        <property name="compressionThreshold" value="1024"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="opTimeout" value="1000"/>
    <property name="timeoutExceptionThreshold" value="1998"/>
    <property name="hashAlg">
        <value type="net.spy.memcached.DefaultHashAlgorithm">KETAMA_HASH</value>
    </property>
    <property name="locatorType" value="CONSISTENT"/> 
    <property name="failureMode" value="Redistribute"/>
    <property name="useNagleAlgorithm" value="false"/>
  </bean>
```

Here’s my FactoryBean

```
package au.com.mycompany;

import net.spy.memcached.AddrUtil;
import net.spy.memcached.ClientMode;
import net.spy.memcached.ConnectionFactoryBuilder;
import net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient;
import net.spy.memcached.spring.MemcachedClientFactoryBean;

public class MyMemcachedClientFactoryBean extends MemcachedClientFactoryBean {
    private final ConnectionFactoryBuilder connectionFactoryBuilder = new ConnectionFactoryBuilder();
    private String servers;

    @Override
    public Object getObject() throws Exception {
        if (servers.contains("127.0.0.1")) {
           connectionFactoryBuilder.setClientMode(ClientMode.Static);
        } else {
           connectionFactoryBuilder.setClientMode(ClientMode.Dynamic);
        }
        return new MemcachedClient(connectionFactoryBuilder.build(), AddrUtil.getAddresses(servers));
    }

    @Override
    public void setServers(final String newServers) {
        this.servers = newServers;
    }
}
```